# Double integral question reverse order?

Tags: integration

I have to change the orderof the following integrals.

a) $\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x f(x,y) dy$

b) $\int_0^a dx \int_y^{a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} f(x,y) dy$

c) $\int_0^1 dx \int_{x^2}^x f(x,y) dy$

I have been solving many integrals but I havent seen any question like this..the problem is that I looked online and I dont understand it,i only understand that Im only supposed to do change dxdy to dydx..but how?

Comment: I've edited your question. Please make sure the it's correct. Also, you can learn the basics on how to type math in this site here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: Should the limits in the inner integral of b) really depend on $y$?

Comment: yes they should depend..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw the region over which you are integrating on a piece of paper. For example, the region of integration for part (a) is a triangle. Can you see why?